# deserializing pointer from struct gives pointer to pointer?

Tags: c++, pointers, memory

Given the following structures:

```c
// sizeof == 8
struct Data {
    int Foo;
    int Bar;
};

// sizeof == 16
struct __declspec(align(8)) Consumer {
    char Padder00[4];
    char Padder01[4];
    
    Data* Data;
};
```

I'd expect the `Data*` to be equal to a number, spanning over 8 bytes (as I'am on x64), which is the the start address of an structure of type `Data`.

Now, debbuging following example:

```c
int main()
{
    Consumer consumer;
    consumer.Data = (Data*)malloc(sizeof(Data));
    // consumer.Data    == 0x0000013c86eb1300
    // &consumer.Data   == 0x00000037cdcff660

    consumer.Data->Bar = 1337;
    consumer.Data->Foo = 42069;
    
    char* stepper = (char*)(&consumer);
    stepper += 4;           // skipping 1st padder
    stepper += 4;           // skipping 2nd padder
    
    Data* restored = ((Data*)stepper);
    // restored         == 0x00000037cdcff660
    //                  == &consumer.Data

    free(consumer.Data);
    std::getchar();
    return 0;
}
```

So `restored == &consumer.Data` whereas I would've expected it to be `restored == consumer.Data`, going further and looking at each byte of `stepper` yields the following:

```c
stepper[0] = 0x00
stepper[1] = 0x13
stepper[2] = 0xeb
stepper[3] = 0x86
stepper[4] = 0x3c
stepper[5] = 0x01
stepper[6] = 0x00
stepper[7] = 0x00

// 0x0000013c86eb1300 (little endian)
// 0x0000013c86eb1300 == consumer.Data
```

##### Summing up:

`((Data*)stepper) == &consumer.Data == (*(Data**)stepper)`

where I expect it to be

`((Data*)stepper) == consumer.Data`

So... what kinda sorcery exactly is happening here?

Comment: Why do you expect anything else? `stepper` starts by pointing at the beginning of the `Consumer` object, then you step through the object by adding integers. At the end you still point into the `Consumer` object, nowhere else. Using the result from the cast `(Data*)stepper` causes undefined behavior, because there is no `Data` object at the location `stepper` points to. There is just a `Data*` there.

Comment: Your expectation is incorrect.   `stepper` is the *address of* the pointer `consumer.Data`, not its value.  So what you are seeing is that `((Data*)stepper) == &consumer.Data`.

Comment: Do the same thing but with `int` instead of `Data*` - do you expect `(int) stepper` to be the *value* of the `int`? (There is nothing special about pointers.)

Comment: @molbdnilo thanks! that made it clear. I guess I was just overthinking or something.

Answer (score 0):

The mistake is this line

```
Data* restored = ((Data*)stepper);
```

it should be

```
Data* restored = *((Data**)stepper);
```

`stepper` points at the location where `Data` (the field) is, which itself is a pointer. So dereferencing `stepper` gives you the `Data` pointer and you need to dereference that to get the `Data`.

Comment: It might be easier to follow with the more explicit  `Data **address_of_restored = (Data **)stepper;  Data *restored = *address_of_restored;`